# Ran geth --light, sync at 0%

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, windows

So sync the whole chain just takes way too long for me, after a whole day of work it wasn't even halfway.

I ran the geth --light command and it seems to work. It is showing the correct amount of ether.

But i noticed I have two versions of geth 1.6.5 and 1.6.6
I removed 1.6.5 but then the wallet shows 0 ether, so i restored it.
It's also seems to be stuck at 0% sync now, i'm not sure if I should just leave it like this or that I can set it up to use 1.6.6 instead?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to leave one version of geth - 1.6.6 with synced chaindata. If you want to keep your accounts (or `wallet` as you call it) you may move the `keystore` folder from 1.6.5 version to 1.6.6. For more details please refer to [geth docs with detailed instructions](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Backup-&-restore). Please remember to first backup or copy the keystore before deleting the geth distribution